# Swift2でRealmを使いたい

Tags: swift, realm

Realmを勉強中です。
Swift2にインストールしたいのですが、できません。

ターミナルでsh build.sh buildするが、buildできていない。 
cdにてrealm-cocoa-masterに移動して実行しているが、できない。

わかる方、教えていただけたら幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、フレームワークをビルドできないのを解決しましょう。
下記の手順の通りにやってください。

1. Xcode 7のコマンドラインツールを使うように切り替えます。
   6でも7でもいいのでXcodeを起動して`Xcode>Preferences...`メニューを開きます。
   LocationsタブのCommand Line Tools:の所でXcode 7.0を選択します。
   （下の画像の赤い部分を参考にしてください）
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. realm-cocoaのリポジトリをクローンします。
   `$ git clone git@github.com:realm/realm-cocoa.git`
3. クローンしたリポジトリに移動します。
   `$ cd realm-cocoa/`
4. 念のため、コマンドラインツールのバージョンを確認します。`xcodebuild -version`とコマンドを入力して、`Xcode 7.0`と表示されればOKです。
   `$ xcodebuild -version`
   `Xcode 7.0`
   `Build version 7A176x`
5. 念のため、masterブランチにいることを確認します。`git branch`と入力して、`master`にマークが付いていればOKです。
   `$ git branch`
6. iOSでSwift用のフレームワークをビルドします。`sh build.sh ios-swift`とコマンドを入力します。
   `$ sh build.sh ios-swift`

ここまでで、下の画像のように、`build/ios/swift2.0/`ディレクトリにRealm.frameworkとRealmSwift.frameworkが作られていると思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もし、この時点で失敗しているようでしたら、表示されているエラーメッセージなどを教えてください。

このあとは、プロジェクトをXcodeで開いて、Realm.frameworkとRealmSwift.frameworkをプロジェクト設定のEmbedded Binariesにドラッグ＆ドロップします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これでひとまずプロジェクトで利用できるようになります。

詳しい使い方などは[ドキュメント](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)を参照の上、わからないことがありましたらまたお聞きください。

Comment: 初心者で基本的なことかもしれませんが、2~5をどのようにしたらいいのかよくわかりません。
コマンドラインでするのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 初心者で基本的なことかもしれませんが、2をどのようにしたらいいのかよくわかりません。YかNを延々と求めてきます。
3のディレクトリがどこにあるのか？できていないのかもしれません。

どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: ターミナルで`$ sh build.sh build`したと書かれていたので、3まではご存知だと思っていました。
では、`git clone ...`の代わりにダウンロードしたものを使いましょう。 https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa に行って右側の真ん中あたりに「Download ZIP」というボタンがあります。それを押すと、リポジトリがダウンロードできます（手順の2代わり）。
そうしたらコマンドラインで`$ cd realm-cocoa-master/`（ダウンロードしたものはフォルダ名が少し違います。）と入力してディレクトリに移動できたらあとは4以降の手順を実行してください。

Comment: ちなみに、Swift 2はまだ正式版ではないので申請はできませんし、Xcodeも不安定だったりするので、Swift 1.2で開発するほうがわかりやすいのではないでしょうか。Realmについても、Swift 1.2ならわざわざRealmをビルドしなくても、Webサイトからダウンロードしたものを使えますので。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。
Swift2を使うのは、初心者で、提出できる頃にはiOS9が出ている頃になると思っているからです。Swift1で作ると、修正の手間がかなりかかると思っています。
親切ご丁寧な解説に感謝いたします。

Comment: 「Swift2でRealmを使いたい、その2」も教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。