# Realmをswiftで使いたいのですが、初心者にわかりやすいページはありませんか。

Tags: swift

swift6.3.2でデータを扱うiphoneのアプリを作りたい初心者です。coredataよりRealmが使いやすそうなのでRealmのインストールからprojectへの組み込みなどで初心者にわかりやすいページはないでしょうか。全く初心者向きではないというのであれば諦めますが、なんとか使いたいのです。

Answer (score 3):

まずは公式サイトのマニュアルに詳しくセットアップ方法が書かれていますので、それをご覧になってください。

https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/#swift-20

下記のStackOverflowの回答にはスクリーンショット付きで、補足説明がありますので、こちらも参考にしてください。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/14186/5519

CocoaPodsを使ったことがあるなら、下記の記事もわかりやすいです。
（CocoaPodsが何かわからない場合は却って難しいと思いますので無視してください。）

http://qiita.com/g08m11/items/e8a525490b5113c052a7

それでもうまくいかなかったり、困った場合は、Realmではチャットによるサポートがありますので、そこで相談されると良いと思います。チャットなので込み入った内容でも丁寧にサポートできます。
http://slack.realm.io

またはFacebookのユーザーグループで相談されるのも良いと思います。
https://www.facebook.com/groups/realmjp/

Answer (score 1):

Qiitaで見かけました、参考になれば嬉しいです。
http://qiita.com/roana0229/items/e641da94ab4ebad46b4c