# Realmがbuild できない

Tags: swift, ios, macos, realm, watchkit

watchOS3(swift3.0)用のRealm.framework, RealmSwift.frameworkが必要になり、リポジトリをbuildしましたがエラーが出ます。

記事[Rwift2でRealmを使いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/13165/swift2%E3%81%A7realm%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)を参考に下記手順を実施しました。
1. Xcode8(8A218a)のコマンドラインツールを選択。-->>記事のXcode7を8に読み替えています。
2. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa よりリポジトリーをダウンロード
3. sh build.sh ios-swift                -->> エラー発生, buildも同じ

ログが非常に大きいため、下記エラー部分のみを抜粋しています。
もし、解析に必要ば部分があればおしらせください。追加掲載します。

お判りの方がおられたなら、ご教授いただきたく、よろしくお願いします。

```
CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_change_builder.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_change_builder.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
...............
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/hogehoge/Desktop/REALM/realm-cocoa-master/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_change_builder.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_notifications.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
................
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/hogehoge/Desktop/REALM/realm-cocoa-master/Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_notifier.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_notifier.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
.................
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/hogehoge/Desktop/REALM/realm-cocoa-master/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_notifier.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/external_commit_helper.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/apple/external_commit_helper.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
.................
external_commit_helper.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_change_builder.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_change_builder.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_notifications.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/collection_notifier.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_notifier.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/DerivedData/Realm/Build/Intermediates/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/external_commit_helper.o Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/apple/external_commit_helper.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サブモジュールが取得できていません。
少し前にObjectStoreというAPI層を共通化するC++のコードを別リポジトリで管理するようになりました。そのため、ビルドするにはサブモジュールも合わせて取得する必要があります。

サブモジュールを取得するにはリポジトリのルートディレクトリで下記のコマンドを実行します。

```
git submodule update --init
```

そのあと、通常の手順でビルドしてください。

Comment: ご指摘の通りサブモジュールを取得することで、buildに成功しました。各OSのswift−3.0 frameworkが生成されました。早速のご回答、ありがとうございました。